# MySQL sum of table sums with different where clauses

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause, multiple-tables

Trying to sum multiple sums from different tables with different where conditions for each table.

Here's my 3 sums:

```
SELECT SUM(1column2) FROM table1 WHERE 1column1 = '0';
SELECT SUM(1column4) FROM table1 WHERE 1column3 = '0';
SELECT SUM(2column2) FROM table2 WHERE 2column1 = '0' AND 2column3 = 'w' AND 2column4 != 'f';
```

The result needs to be `(first sum) - (second sum) - (third sum)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL supports basic operators, so you should be able to do something as simple as:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(1column2) FROM table1 WHERE 1column1 = '0') - (SELECT SUM(1column4) FROM table1 WHERE 1column3 = '0') - (SELECT SUM(2column2) FROM table2 WHERE 2column1 = '0' AND 2column3 = 'w' AND 2column4 != 'f');
```

I'm sure this can be optimized, but that should give you what you need (and without better information on the relationships, optimization would be difficult).

Comment: Thanks for trying.  Still says "no database selected".

Comment: are all 3 tables in the same database? have you tried "use <database name>"?

Comment: Jeez, that was dumb on my part.  Hadn't selected a db in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make each of those queries subqueries to an outer query that performs your desired summation:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(1column2) FROM table1 WHERE 1column1 = '0')
  - (SELECT SUM(1column4) FROM table1 WHERE 1column3 = '0')
  - (SELECT SUM(2column2) FROM table2 WHERE 2column1 = '0' 
      AND 2column3 = 'w' AND 2column4 != 'f');
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but "no database selected".  Man, I was hoping it was that easy.

Comment: @user1382306: Well if you've not selected your desired database, your original `SELECT` statements won't succeed either.  Specify your database name when you connect, or issue a [`USE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html) statement.

Comment: Jeez, that was dumb on my part.  Hadn't selected a db in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @user1382306: Glad to hear you worked it out.  FYI, you should [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if they solve your problem and [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) them if they're useful or helpful.